# How do I format a 0 to an empty string in a viewmodel property

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

My objective is to have an empty string returned when the value of a property is 0 (zero) and the value otherwise.

I looked at the DisplayFormat attribute but I don't see how that is set up conditionally (except for null).

I also tried to use code for the get method for the property but I get a stack overflow error trying it this way.

```
public class Results
{
    public string TestId
    { 
       get 
       {
           if ( TestId == "0" ) { return ""; };
           return TestId;
       } 
       set {} 
    }
}
```

There must be a way but apparently this isn't it, or I'm missing something.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `private string _TestId; public string TestId { get {return _TestId == "0" ? string.Empty : _TestId; } set {_TestId = value; } }` Although if your saying its a view model, then that would not makes sense (you would just set the value of the property in the view model only if the data model value is not "0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code approach should work. The problem you're facing is because you refer to the same `TestId` property from the getter.
You should instead refer to the underlying field, which stores the value.
I'd suggest to change that as follows:

```
public class Results
{
    private string _testId;

    public string TestId
    {
        get => _testId == "0" ? string.Empty : _testId;
        set => _testId = value;
    } 
}
```